Does every regular foliation admits a transversal regular foliation?
Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold (compact, orietnted, or some other extra nice conditions), let $D\subset TM$ be an integrable distribution (i.e, $[D,D]\subset D$), then by Frobenius theorem, $D$ determines a regular foliation $\mathcal{F}$ on $M$.
My question is, does there exist another regular foliation $\mathcal{E}$ which is transversal to $\mathcal{F}$ in sense that each two leaves of $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ meet transversally?
Or in other words, can we find an appropriate Riemnnian metric $g$ on $M$ such that the normal distribution $D^{\perp}\subset TM$ is also integrable?

Take the Hopf fibration of $S^3$ over $S^2$. This is a 1-dimensional foliation without a transversal foliation.

To convert my comment to an answer:
First of all, if you start with a codimension 1 foliation, it admits a transversal 1-dimensional foliation (since every 1-dimensional distribution is involutive). In general, I am reading your question as asking about existence of a transversal foliation of complementary dimension (i.e. dimension of $\mathcal E$ equals codimension of $\mathcal F$). An example when such a transversal foliation does not exist is given by the Hopf fibration $\pi: S^3\to S^2$.  Fibers of $\pi$ define a 1-dimensional foliation $\mathcal F$ of $S^3$. A (2-dimensional) transversal distribition $D$ to $\mathcal F$ would be an Ehresmann connection $\nabla$ on $\pi: S^3\to S^2$. A distribution $D$ is involutive if and only if the connection $\nabla$ is flat (has zero curvature). But a flat Ehresmann bundle over a simply-connected bas is necessarily trivial and Hopf fibration is not. Even more, if $\nabla$ is an Ehresmann connection on  $\pi: S^3\to S^2$ then it does not have a single complete connected leaf (a complete hypersurface $H$ tangent to the distribution $D$). The way to see this is to observe that the restriction of $\pi$ to such $H$ would be a local diffeomorphism with path-lifting property (by completeness of $H$), hence, a covering map. But $S^2$ does not admit a nontrivial  coverings, hence, $H$ has to be a 2-sphere, which is, of course, impossible since Hopf fibration has no nontrivial sections.

That's a very nice example! Thank you for the help
